# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 - Google Mobile Ads

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob

I'm trying to add Google Mobile Ads SDK 7.6

But i'm getting a lot of errors, and i can't solve it. Under here i have some of the errors.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey", referenced from:
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animateTransition:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForRestoringAnimationToSavedState:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
  "_UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey", referenced from:
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animateTransition:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForTopToBottomAnimationPresentationWithTransitionContext:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForBottomToTopAnimationPresentationWithTransitionContext:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScrollView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADSlot+SwipeToViewController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPasteboard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADAdView.o)
  "_UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum", referenced from:
      -[GADMRAIDPicture storeImage:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADMRAIDPicture.o)
  "_CGSizeFromString", referenced from:
      _GADCGSizeFromString in GoogleMobileAds(GADAdSize.o)
  "_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced from:
      -[GADAdView(VideoAdditions) rotateVideoToDegrees:] in GoogleMobileAds(GADAdView+VideoAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GADImpressionTicketGestureRecognizer in GoogleMobileAds(GADImpressionTicketGestureRecognizer.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GADAdViewTouchGestureRecognizer in GoogleMobileAds(GADAdViewTouchGestureRecognizer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADImpressionTicketGestureRecognizer in GoogleMobileAds(GADImpressionTicketGestureRecognizer.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADAdViewTouchGestureRecognizer in GoogleMobileAds(GADAdViewTouchGestureRecognizer.o)
  "_UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric", referenced from:
      -[GADBannerView intrinsicContentSize] in GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerView.o)
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I had to use the `@import GoogleMobileAds;` instead of using `#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>`

That solved my problem.